# Pigeonhole Elementary School has 500 students. Show that at least two of them were born on the same day of the year.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I'm having a hard time grasping the concept of pigeon hole problems, can someone give me a step by step of how they would solve this pigeon hole problem? like an algorithmic approach

Comment: Hint: there are more students than days in a year.

Comment: Well, what would happen if this weren't the case? How would you even construct such a scenario where there are 500 students but two of them *aren't* born on the same day of the year. I would try doing this to gain more intuition as to why the pigeonhole principle works.

Comment: The concept of pigeon hole problems is simply this:  If there are more occurrences then there are ways for the occurrences to be different, then some of the occurrences must be the same.  There are 366 days of the year (including leap year) and 500 students.  There are more students than there are birthdays.  So some students must have the same birthdays because there are not enough birthdays to go around.  It's the same thing, if there are 6 slices of pie and 7 students some students must share or have no pie.  That's  all there is.

Comment: I've downvoted this question, because a simple Google search for "pigeonhole principle" would have immediately returned results. Heck, "pigeonhole elementary school" returns an answer key for a homework set with literally this exact problem on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the analogy on this exemple , if you have 13 persons , there are atleast 2 born on same month, since there are only 12 months in the year,they could all be born on same month ofcourse but  we can be sure that ATLEAST 2 of them was born on same month .

Comment: ok i see that makes sense

Answer (score 7):

Let's look at this student by student.

If the second student has the same birthday as the first student, we have two students with the same birthday, so we are done. So suppose the second student was born on a different day from the first student.

Now let's look at the third student. If she shares a birthday with one of the previous two students, again we are done. So let's suppose that each of the first three students have a different birthday.

Continue in this fashion until we get to student 366. If any of the previous 365 students shared a birthday, we would have finished, so each of students 1 to 365 must have a different birthday. In other words, we have a student with a birthday on each of the 365 days of the year. So whenever student number 366 has her birthday, she shares her birthday with some student.

Hence two students share a birthday.

Comment: No student can be born on February 29? `;-)` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gioachino_Rossini

Answer (score 4):

Imagine to have one box for each day of the year, including February 29, which makes $366$ boxes.

Now, imagine that each student drops a copy of their ID in the box corresponding to their birthday. Some boxes might turn out to be empty, say they are in number of $E$. So the students dropped their ID in $366-E$ boxes. If each of the nonempty boxes contains exactly one ID, the number of students would be $366-E<500$.

Answer (score 3):

There are $365$ days in a year .Since there are $500$ students, therefore atleast 2 students(pigeons) must have the same birthdate(pigeonhole). In fact, there are atleast $500-(365+1)=134$ students, amongst whom atleast $2$ share a date of birth.

Comment: `there are atleast 500−365=135 students with the same date of birth` This doesn't follow.

Comment: @dxiv why does it not follow?

Comment: Not *all* $135$ must have the *same* birthday. Suppose each of the first $135$ days of the year has $2$ students born on it, then the remaining days only one.

Comment: @dxiv ok, understood. Modified the answer.

Comment: No, the 135 students (actually 134) might all have different birthdays. There are at least 134 students who share their birthday with at least another student.

Comment: @egreg thanks, edited the post

Answer (score 3):

Just count the worst case scenario. If you have 500 students, let's begin by trying to make sure all their days that they were born at are different, starting with placing **Student 1** at January 1, then **Student 2** at January 2 and so on...

Eventually we get to **Student 365** and place him/her on December 31 (assuming no leap years, the argument is easily extended to include that, there are 365 days in a year). Now where can we place **Student 366** so that the day he was born doesn't fall on anyone else's?

And looking back at our students, we still have 135 students left to place!

Answer (score 3):

Take a slightly different question: What is the maximum number of students the school can have if no two pupils are born on the same day?

Since there are at most 366 days in a year, and on each day either none or one pupil was born, there can be at most 366 students.

Comment: Simple and effective, I like it.

Answer (score 1):

There are 7 days in a week and you supposed to meet 8 people, so you have to meet at least 2 on same day.
all these problems have same strukture , but in some problem can dirichlet principle give some surprising good results.